# re-displaying the same drop-down in HTML below original drop-down option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
   $("select").after("<br>here");
   
   //window.alert("We're getting somewhere!")
   //document.write("#1");   
  });
 });
</script>
<title>Query Tool</title>
</head>
<h1>Organizer Tool</h1>
<HR>
<p>Please choose search criteria:</p>
<select id=1>
 <option value="MMSI">MIMSI</option>
 <option value="Ship Type">shipType</option>
 <option value="Anomaly Type">Anomaly Type</option>
</select>
<button type="button">Search</button>
<body><br><br><br>
 <p>Testing.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm working on an application which interacts with the users via webserver(using **JQuery**) and receives a string which is received from the browser-side in the form of a drop-down option. After having chosen the option, the user is meant to click search and the http request is sent with that string, and received on the server-side at which point it interacts with the database and queries that string. After having found that search, it would print it back out onto the client screen in a tabulated format. 
Now, my problem is with regards to choosing multiple options to query; How can I display a new drop-down menu for each time a user chooses one from the previous one?
I have a novice understanding of event handlers, and realize I can trigger an event on 'change' and display a text; yet can anyone be so kind as to explain how I may display that option drop-down menu below the first one after a 'change' has been detected? 
So far I have been able to display the string 'here' everytime a change occurs in the drop-down.

Thanks so much,
Al

Comment: Google for cascading menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you right, you've been searching something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Query Tool</title>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#first_select").change(function() {
            //$.post('where',{data},function (d) {     //this is to post data to the server and get the answer with function
                // documentation is at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
                // if the answer is in JSON, decode it
                var answer = '[{"ID":"1","name":"Astronomy"},{"ID":"2","name":"Microscopy"},{"ID":"3","name":"Bilogy"}]';
                var d = JSON.parse(answer);

                var s = $("<select id=\"select_two\" name=\"select_two\" />");
                for(var val in d) {
                    $("<option />", {value: d[val].ID, text: d[val].name}).appendTo(s);
                }
                $("#selector_area").empty();
                s.appendTo("#selector_area");



            //}); // closing brackets for the post method
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body><br><br><br>
    <p>Testing.</p>
    <h1>Organizer Tool</h1>
<HR>
<p>Please choose search criteria:</p>
<select id="first_select">
    <option value="MMSI">MIMSI</option>
    <option value="Ship Type">shipType</option>
    <option value="Anomaly Type">Anomaly Type</option>
</select>

<div id="selector_area"></div>
<button type="button">Search</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the closest to what I've been saying.. Instead of just redisplaying 1 extra drop-down I want to be able to redisplay it after each time the newest dropdown has been changed

Comment: So do you want any other improvements to get the idea for the further development of yourself? OR it's ok right now?

Comment: Yeah it was useful.. I was able to reach my end goal.